# Automatic Notepad++ formatting for writing scripts

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey

I'm wondering if anyone had techniques/tips for using Notepad++ for writing scripts. I know real IDE programs I've used for say, python, have a lot of built-in autoformatting. When I write an `IF` statement or `LOOP` it will create some of the bracketing needed. I use Notepad++ for writing AutoHotKey and it works really really well, but would love if it had some auto-formatting capability.

Something like; I type `if` and gets turned into...

```
if ()
  {

  }
```

or typing functions such as `RegExMatch` into... `RegExMatch(,,,)`

If Notepad++ is not the best editor for AHK then what is?

Comment: I think questions that ask for tool recommendations are not allowed on this site... That being said Notepad++ with AHK plugin is better than nothing; SciTE4AHK is very nice but it cannot beat VSCode's plugin ecosystem;  VSCode with AHK plugin is the best I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typing [AHK commands and functions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/index.htm) in [Editors](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Edit.htm#Editors) I use [context-sensitive Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm#variant) with a special [ending char](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) in my main script:

```
        ; === auto-execute section ===  (top of the script)

; create a group of those editors:  
GroupAdd, myEditors, ahk_class Notepad
GroupAdd, myEditors, ahk_class Notepad++
; ...

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

; Hotstring-Options:    
; C0: Case-insensitive
; O: Omit the ending character
; T: Send the replacement text raw
; EndChar: < 
#Hotstring T O C0
#Hotstring EndChars <    

#IfWinActive ahk_group myEditors

::if:: ; type if< to send 
Send {Text}
(
if ()
  {

  }
)
return

; type rexm< or RegExMatch< to send RegExMatch(,,,)
::rexm::RegExMatch(,,,)
::RegExMatch::RegExMatch(,,,)

; ...



 #IfWinActive ; turn off context-sensitivity
```